# How to login a PHP script with another server via HTTP headers?

Tags: php, http, header, metadata, icecast

I'm trying to create a script that will login to an Icecast2 server and grab the metadata for the currently playing tracks. My issue is that the Icecast server is user/pass protected via basic HTTP login.

```
    <?php
        $fp = fsockopen("xxxxxxxx.com", 8000, $errno, $errstr, 30);
        if (!$fp) {
            echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
        } else {
            $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
            $out .= "Icy-MetaData:1\r\n";
            $out .= "Host: xxxxxxxx.com\r\n";
            $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

            fwrite($fp, $out);
            $arr = array();

            while (!feof($fp)) {
                $arr[] = fgets($fp, 128);
            }
            fclose($fp);
        }

        echo json_encode(trim(strip_tags($arr[73])));

?>
```

This is the script that has allowed me to grab metadata before the Icecast server was password protected.

**In short, how do I send a user/pass via this script to the Icecast server to login and grab the info successfully? (Uses htpasswd)**

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: I might be totally wrong here but can't you put the username and password in the address when using basic auth? for example `http://username:password@www.somesite.com` might be worth a shot.

Comment: I saw that solution while googling around and had already tried it, nice try though! It'd be so simple like that. XD

Comment: @Otoris worth noting, if the answer you accepted now works, so should Dale's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), you need the `Authorization: Basic` header and [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) `username:password`.

Code to add:

```
$out .= "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($user .":". $password);
```

Comment: This seems like it's exactly what I'm looking for, but it doesn't appear to be working... Is there a way I can debug this code better?

Comment: Got this to work after looking over and rewriting other portions of my code! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Some research revealed [this](http://www.higherpass.com/php/Tutorials/Using-Curl-To-Query-Remote-Servers/5/).

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_USERPWD, '[username]:[password]')

$data = curl_exec();
curl_close($ch);
```

However, it requires the usage of [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) instead of file sockets.

Comment: I cannot currently use cURL on this server. Otherwise this would be great.

Comment: Two lines in the code miss $ch, these should be:  
 `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '[username]:[password]');`  
 `$data = curl_exec($ch);`

Answer (score 0):

Log in manually to check if the page uses cookies to authenticate users, if it does then you can use headers to send cookies, which should allow you to retrieve data from password protected pages.

```
$array = array(
      'http'=>array(
        'header'=>"Cookie: *cookiedatahere*"
      )
);

$context = stream_context_create($array);

$url = *password protected data source*;
$raw = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```